# Boundary points of union of a semi-closed and an open interval

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let R be the metric space with usual metric. Then what are the boundary points of S=(1 2]U (3 4)?

I think they should be {1 2 3 4}.
But if i use the following two points-

1. Closure of S is union of S and boundary of S
2. Closure of given set is- [1 2] U [3 4]
   (I used accumulation points to find closure)

If i remove S from closure then boundary points seems to be only {1 3 4}.

Please clarify these 2 answers that which one is correct and why?

And also what will be the boundary points if i take the whole space of complex numbers instead of Real numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boundary points of $S=(1,2] \cup (3,4)$ are indeed $\{ 1,2,3,4 \}$ as you say. It is also true that the closure of (any set) $S$ is $S \cup \partial S$. But nobody says this union has to be *disjoint*. $\partial S$ *can* overlap with $S$, and it does in this case: $S \cap \partial S = \{ 2 \}$. So that is why $\partial S \neq \overline S \setminus S$. In this case you only have $\overline S \setminus S \subsetneq \partial S $. In general this inclusion does hold (however it might be strict as it is in this case), because we have even $\partial S = \overline S \setminus Int(S)$.

If you see $S$ as a subset of $\mathbb C$, the answer stays the same: $\partial S = \{ 1,2,3,4 \}$. To see this, one way is to use the characterisations of closure and interior with sequences inside $S$, only this time sequences of complex numbers. But since $S$ is on the $O_x$ axis, any the imaginary part of all elements of all such sequences will be $0$ (sequences have to stay inside $S$).

A quicker way to see it if you know a bit of topology and if you defined closure and interior with closed and open sets instead of sequences is: $S$ is included in $\mathbb R$ and the subspace topology on $\mathbb R$ inherited from $\mathbb C = \mathbb R^2$ (the subspace topology on $X \subseteq Y$ is just the topology where open sets are intersections of open sets in $Y$ with $X$) is the same as the usual topology of $\mathbb R$. Also, if you have the inclusion $X \subseteq Y \subseteq Z$, then the topology $X$ inherits from $Y$ (the topology on $Y$ being the one inherited from $Z$) is the same as the topology $X$ iherits directly from $Z$. So $S$ has the same topology inside $\mathbb R$ as it does inside $\mathbb C$, hence it has the same boundary and closure.

Answer (score 0):

Recall:
Let $A \subseteq \Bbb R$ . A point $x$ in $\Bbb R$ is called a boundary point of $A$ if every neighborhood of $x$ intersect both $A$ and its complement. With this definition, $\partial S=\{1,2,3,4\}$

Note that $\overline{S}=S \cup \partial(S)$ is correct. But $S$ and $\partial S$ are need not be disjoint.

So remove $S$ from $\overline{S}$ need not equal $\partial S$ !